# How to create a unequally sized picture wall?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Im currently developing a little app... its basically my first real app. I want to display a bunch of images in a picture wall like instagram does.

When you take a look at the picture below you may see that there are equally sized sqaure pictures next to bigger square cells... 
I tried to create something similar with the android studio gridview/gridlayout... but it doesnt seem to be possible with that due to the column / row width and height...

Are there any librarys for such picture walls ? 
How would you code/design such a picture wall layout ?

Thanks for your help !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager  mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Try [this](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-recyclerview.html) and [this](http://blog.grafixartist.com/pinterest-masonry-layout-staggered-grid/) tutorial